# Responsive not working on tablet

Tags: css, mobile, viewport, tablet

i'm newbie and i have a site, i want to make a responsive design, it is responsive for mobile but not responsive on tablet, i want create tablet design like pc layout not mobile, can you help me how solved this problem? maybe meta viewport and css wrong code, how many px to create min or max media width? 
this is my dummy site
http://silanycorp.com/a

and this site for check responsive layout
http://ami.responsivedesign.is/#

meta viewport

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

CSS code

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
.container{
    padding:0;
}
.logo{
    padding-left:0;
}
.hide-on-desktop{
    display:block
}
.header-wrapper{
    padding: 0;
}
.header-outer{
```

}

thanks for your help :)

Comment: Do not post a live link (only), instead post the relevant code in your question so others down the road can benefit from the answer given to you.  Thanks!

Comment: Bootstrap that bad boy and all your problems will go away

Comment: this is not use a grid system or column

Answer (score 2):

You can have multiple stylesheets loaded based on the width of the viewport the user has.

This can be accomplished with the following tag:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='css/medium.css' />
```

You can also set it in the stylesheet with something like this:

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  #sidebar ul li a {
    padding-left: 21px;
    background: url(../images/email.png) left center no-repeat;
  }
}
```

Here is a good article on the process: http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/